# The Character has in the Blender view no colour!!

Tags: texturing, 3d-view

My character, the man in the screenshot has no color in the 3D view. I marked it with blue color. There is also a UV texture, which I added to [Image Texture]. Does anyone know how to get the color in the 3D view according to the texture?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the **Viewport Shading** as high lighted below:

[image]

To: **Texture** or **Material**